# How could I view panoramas on IPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to make an app which have one panoramic image, and when I zoom in the image, the view will automatically change the big image to other images with higher resolution, I can arrange images with different resolutions and sizes no problem with that, but I would like to get help of the idea of how to viewing panoramas on iphone.

for example there is a site called http://gigapan.org/ which has in his main page an illustration of what I want.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a UIScrollView, it has methods for zooming and the delegate has a method to return a view for a particular zoom setting. Check the Apple docs for more info.